# OpenCV 2.4.8 cvCaptureFromAVI loads file, but cv::VideoCapture doesn't

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.8 on Windows 7 64. I can load and play my AVI file with the C interface `cvCaptureFromAVI`, but using the C++ interface `cv::VideoCapture`, `cv::VideoCapture.open()` returns always false.

I tried to put `ffmpeg` (static and shared) in my working folder, same problem. Did I need to recompile OpenCV or am I doing it wrong?

Code with C interface:

```
IplImage *frame;
CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("sample.avi");
if ( capture == NULL )
{
    std::cout << "video not ok" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "video ok" << std::endl;
    double videoFPS = cvGetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS );        
    while(frame = cvQueryFrame(capture))
    {
        cvShowImage("Video", frame);
        cvWaitKey(1000/videoFPS);
    }
    cvDestroyWindow("Video");
    cvReleaseImage(&frame);
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
}
```

Code with C++ interface:

```
cv::Mat frame;
cv::VideoCapture capture;
cv::namedWindow("Video");
if(capture.open("sample.avi"))
{
    std::cout << "video ok" << std::endl;
    double videoFPS = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
    int nbFrames = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
    for(int i=0;i<nbFrames;i++)
    {
        capture >> frame;
        imshow("Video", frame);
        cv::waitKey(1000/videoFPS);
    }
}
else
{
    std::cout << "video not ok" << std::endl;
}
```

Thank you for your help.